# How to wrap python script into bash script so that when using nohup the output is redirected in online manner?

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script `script.py`

```
from time import sleep
    for i  in range(30):
    print(i)
    sleep(1)
```

I wrap this script into bash script `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 python_test.py
```

I want to run the bash script with `nohup` and redirect the output to `output.out`. Thus I run the linux command:

```
nohup bash script.sh > output.out &
```

However, the output is redirected to `output.out` only when the python script 'script.py' ends, not in the online manner. Thus the question.

**Question.** How to redirect the output to `output.out` into online manner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telling nohup to write output in real-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235928/telling-nohup-to-write-output-in-real-time)

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. `nohup unbuffer bash script.sh > output.out &` does the job. Thanks (;

Comment: no bash scripting is needed , put `#!/usr/bin/env python3` shebang into your python script.